# Kivy `Logger` treats Python exception as warning in `PYTHON` mode

Tags: python, logging, kivy

I'm using this basic configuration for logging a Kivy app:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(
    filename = "log.log",
    filemode = "w",
    encoding = "utf-8",
    force = True,
    level = logging.INFO,
    format = "%(asctime)s %(levelname) -8s %(message)s",
    datefmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
)

from kivy.logger import Logger, LOG_LEVELS
Logger.mode = "PYTHON"
```

If I raise an exception manually:

```
raise NameError("Bad name")
```

This is the log file:

```
2023-11-05 12:47:36 INFO     deps: Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.3
2023-11-05 12:47:36 INFO     Logger: Record log in C:\Users\acgc9\.kivy\logs\kivy_23-11-05_75.txt
2023-11-05 12:47:36 INFO     deps: Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
2023-11-05 12:47:36 INFO     deps: Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.6.0
2023-11-05 12:47:36 INFO     Kivy: v2.2.1
2023-11-05 12:47:36 INFO     Kivy: Installed at "C:\Users\acgc9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
2023-11-05 12:47:36 INFO     Python: v3.11.4 (tags/v3.11.4:d2340ef, Jun  7 2023, 05:45:37) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]
2023-11-05 12:47:36 INFO     Python: Interpreter at "C:\Users\acgc9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"
2023-11-05 12:47:36 INFO     Logger: Purge log fired. Processing...
2023-11-05 12:47:36 INFO     Logger: Purge finished!
2023-11-05 12:47:36 WARNING  stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-11-05 12:47:36 WARNING  stderr:   File "C:\Users\acgc9\Desktop\test.py", line 15, in <module>
2023-11-05 12:47:36 WARNING  stderr:     raise NameError("Bad name")
2023-11-05 12:47:36 WARNING  stderr: NameError: Bad name
```

So the exception is treated as warning and I don't want that, because the program is aborted.

Comment: If you don't want the exception to abort your program, you need to use `try` and `except`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson that is not the problem, the problem is that the exception is an error and it is being logged as a warning (and it is an error because the program is aborted, not that I want to avoid abortion).